# django template tag pass as parameter of another template tag

Tags: django, django-templates, templatetags

Is there a way to pass the result of a template tag to another template tag?

I have 2 custom template tag as following:

```
@register.simple_tag
def foo():
    return foo_value

@register.simple_tag
def bar(value):
    return bar_value + value
```

and I want to to use them in my template like this:

```
{% load my_custom_tags %}
{% bar foo %}
```

I also use `{% with %}` block but failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use an `as` expression part in a template tag to store the result in a variable. For example:

```
{% load my_custom_tags %}
{% foo as foo_result %}
{% bar foo_result %}
```